# Subdomain Routing with asp.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes

My application is using MapRoute with MVC 4.

I want to deploy my site with subdomains base on cities.
Exemple: montreal.domain.com 
NewYork.domain.com

I created a subdomain montreal.domain.com point to same folder as domain.com
However when I run it does not work as expected. Did I do something wrong in the code below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "Default", // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, area = "" },
       new[] { "domain.Web.Controllers" }
        // Parameter defaults
);

// 03/25/2015
routes.Add("Mysite", new DomainRoute("{url}.domain.com", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", url = "" }));
```

Comment: What did it do, and what did you expect it to do?

Comment: Well, it show montreal.domain.com in 1 sec then goes to domain.com
I wanted it to stay on montreal.domain.com so that i can show staff for montreal for example